# Few questions/issues with regard to mvvmcross

Tags: mvvm, mvvmcross

We are planning to build a poker app that targets WPF (Win 7,8), Windows Store (Win 8 Modern UI) and Windows Phone 8 and want to use mvvmcross for the same. I was testing out a few things after installing Ninja Coder for mvvmcross.

**1.** 
The Windows Phone 8 project generated by Ninja Coder (3.0.2) is not in a buildable state. I get an error in the project for the line FastApplicationSwitcingService.Initialize(). I commented the same to build the project successfully, but the app does not run on the emulator at all. What do I need to do to fix this?

**2.** 
The default project structure created by NinjaCoder has a class named FirstViewModel in the core project and FirstView in the platform specific projects. I didn't want any View or ViewModels in the main Core or Platform projects. I wanted them to be in separate assemblies. So I created two more assemblies and moved the FirstView and FirstViewModel into these assemblies.

I then added overrides for GetViewAssemblies and GetViewModelAssemblies in setup.cs to load the newly created view and viewmodel assemblies. Now the problem is how do I locate and load the starting view which is in another assembly. For instance, I may want to use an Id or Name to indicate which start view I want to show and the same may be present in any one of the assemblies loaded. What is the best way to do this?

As a test, I tried using the IMvxViewModelByNameLookup to get the ViewModel type from Name and tried to pass it to ShowViewModel. I was able to show the view this way, but is it the right approach?

**3.** 
Is there any documentation detailing all the classes and interfaces exposed by mvvmcross. The documentation in github seems to be only covering specific use cases.

Comment: For issues about the Ninja Coder, I recommend you raise issues directly on the project site https://github.com/asudbury/NinjaCoderForMvvmCross. For your second question, I'd suggest maybe try editing the question a little - I'm finding it hard to understand what you've done at present (sorry). For the 3rd question, most people seem to start with blogs, magazine articles, the N+1 video tutorials and the wiki. Additional community contributions - including on docs - are always welcome.

Comment: Regarding my second point, I have updated the description  to be more clear about what I was trying to do.